# bash :: visually distinguishing hard links on ls

Tags: symbolic-link, hardlink

I am using **bash** shell in Ubuntu precise.

I am partial to *symbolic links* in **bash** even when a *hard link* would make more sense because they can be more easily identified with an **ls**. In contrast, for *hard links* I have  to visually compare the **inode** numbers. This is more cumbersome compared to the output of **ls** on a soft link which shows the target with "-->" and can have a different colouring scheme applied. Is there a way to have **ls** visually differentiate hard links from "normal files"? E.g. perhaps by colouring differently files with a reference count of more than 1?

I understand that the question is not framed correctly as conceptually a hard link is just another name for the inode and so indistinguishable from a "normal file" and that there is no concept of a target as in symbolic links but you get my use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ls -l` output shows the number of hard links to a file system entry between permissions and owner:

```
$ mkdir foo
$ ls -ld foo
drwxr-xr-x  2 danielbeck  staff  68 15 Aug 18:49 foo
```

It's `2` by default for empty directories, `foo/.` and `foo`. Every subdirectory adds one for its `..`. Unless you're on OS X and of questionable sanity, that's the only directory hard links you'll get.

Files, of course, only show "real" hard links, so anything but `1` indicates there's a hard link somewhere:

```
$ touch bar
$ ln bar baz
$ ls -l bar baz
-rw-r--r--  2 danielbeck  staff  0 15 Aug 18:52 bar
-rw-r--r--  2 danielbeck  staff  0 15 Aug 18:52 baz
```

---

My (BSD/OS X) `ls` has no options related to hard links, but you can write your own shell function, like the following, that prints only the hard link count and otherwise is `ls -F1` (if `ls -l` is too cumbersome):

```
function lss {
    OLDIFS="$IFS"
    IFS=$'\n'
    for line in $( ls -d1 $@ )
        do stat -f '%N%T (%l)' "$line"
    done
    IFS="$OLDIFS"
}
```

Output for the two hardlinks and an unrelated file `qux`:

```
$ lss bar baz qux
bar (2)
baz (2)
qux (1)
```